# Account registration phrases

Tags: register

An applications asks user to provide a phone number. When the number is wrong, the application displays a message. There can be two cases:

1) the phone is correct, but another user already used it for registration;
2) the phone is incorrect (has wrong format).

Is it correct to say:

1) "This phone number is used by another user. Please provide a different one".
2) "Invalid phone number. Please check and try again.".

Or may be there is a better way to write these messages?

Comment: Per the FAQ, questions asking, "Please proofread my document ('are there any mistakes in this text?')" are off-topic; this looks like one of those. However, in answer to your question,, I would probably change #1 to, "This phone number is already in use. Please enter a different one."

Comment: You might also try signing into AOL/Gmail/Yahoo/whatever with a email addresses you know exist and ones you know cannot be real addresses, then adapting their phrasing for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd phrase it this way:

1. This phone number is already used by another user. Please check the information. If you think you've entered the correct number, make sure that you're not already registered, or get in contact with us.
2. The phone number you've entered is invalid. Please check and correct it to ensure that it is in the correct format.

And please make sure that you write "have" ("are") instead of "'ve" ("'re'") if it's formal.